# CSS is lost when going back (browser button)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, laravel

I am creating a CMS for which you used laravel in its version 7 along with bootstrap 4 and jquery. My problem is that when I click the back button of Google Chrome (this does not happen in Firefox), the CSS is lost. Check the console and it is precisely that, they do not load the CSS or the external JAVASCRIPTS, this happens when I am listing the publications and I advance a page. For example, being on the first page does not give me any problem, but if I advance to the second, I select an article and then I go back this happens.

[image]

This is when the design is lost

[image]

I am listing the articles through the laravel pager, however I am using AJAX to not reload the whole page, I do it through an external file that is loaded inside the main view. I also have a file called master.blade.php that contains the JAVASCRIPTS and CSS that I use for web design functionality (eg Bootstrap and JQuery). This file also contains the menu.

PostController

```
    public function show(Request $request){

    $posts = DB::table('posts as posts')->select(['posts.id','posts.title', 'posts.content','posts.url_clean','posts.posted',
    'posts.category_id','posts.created_at', 'posts.updated_at','categories.title AS 
    category_name'])->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'posts.category_id')
    ->orderBy('posts.id','DESC')->paginate(5);
    
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        //return view('dashboard.posts.show_load', ['posts' => $posts ])->render(); 
        return view('dashboard.posts.show_load', compact('posts')); 
    }

    else{
        //return view("dashboard.posts.show", ['posts' => $posts ]);
        return view('dashboard.posts.show', compact('posts'));
    }

}
```

show.blade.php

This is the page where the articles are listed, when clicking on the pager, via AJAX it calls show_load.blade.php

```
    <?php
use App\Http\Controllers\dashboard\PostController;
?>
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('banner')
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div id="banner_1">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/banner1.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style="position:inherit; z-index:1; " alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
@endsection


@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <br></br>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-9">

   
      <div id="posts_data_list">
        @include('dashboard.posts.show_load')
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
        <span class="text-muted">Buscar</span>
        <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">3</span>
      </h4>
      <ul class="list-group mb-3">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
          <div>
            <h6 class="my-0">Product name</h6>
            <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
          </div>
          <span class="text-muted">$12</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
          <div>
            <h6 class="my-0">Second product</h6>
            <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
          </div>
          <span class="text-muted">$8</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
          <div>
            <h6 class="my-0">Third item</h6>
            <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
          </div>
          <span class="text-muted">$5</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between bg-light">
          <div class="text-success">
            <h6 class="my-0">Promo code</h6>
            <small>EXAMPLECODE</small>
          </div>
          <span class="text-success">-$5</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
          <span>Total (USD)</span>
          <strong>$20</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <form class="card p-2">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Promo code">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Redeem</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
@endsection

@section('javascript')
<script type="text/javascript">
var posts =  <?php echo json_encode($posts); ?>;
console.log(posts);

$(function () {
        $('body').on('click', '.pagination a', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#load').append('<img style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 10000;" src="https://i.imgur.com/v3KWF05.gif />');
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            window.history.pushState("", "", url);
            load_posts(url);
        });

        function load_posts(url) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url
            }).done(function (data) {
                $('#posts_data_list').html(data);
            }).fail(function () {
                console.log("Failed to load data!");
            });
        }
    });

window.onhashchange =function() {
  location.reload();
}
</script>
@endsection
```

show_load.blade.php

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\dashboard\PostController;
?>


<div id="load" style="position: relative;">
@foreach ($posts as $post)
           <?php


            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            @$doc->loadHTML($post->content);

            $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
            $img_array = array();

            if (count($images) >=1 ) {
            
                for ($i=0; $i <count($images) ; $i++) { 
                    $img_array[] = $images[$i]->getAttribute('src');
                }
            }

            //else{ $img_array[] = ""; }
            
            //echo $img_array[0];

                

            echo '<div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">';
                if (empty($img_array)) {
                    echo  '<img src="'.asset("img/layouts/no_imagen.png").'" class="w-100">';
                }
                else{
                  echo '<img src="'.$img_array[0].'" class="w-100" >';
                }
                 
          echo  '</div>
             <div class="col-md-8 px-3">
              <div class="card-block px-3">
                <h4 class="card-title">'.$post->title.'</h4>';
                echo '<a href="#" class="btn-outline-danger"><small>'.$post->category_name.',</small></a> ';
                $tags = (new PostController)->tag_list_single($post->id);
                for ($i=0; $i < count($tags) ; $i++) { 
                  //echo '<a href="#" class="btn-outline-info"><small>'.$tags[$i]["title"].',</small></a> ';
                  if ($i == count($tags) - 1) {
                    echo '<a href="#" class="btn-outline-info"><small>'.$tags[$i]["title"].'</small></a> ';
                  }
                  else{ echo '<a href="#" class="btn-outline-info"><small>'.$tags[$i]["title"].',</small></a> ';}
                }
  
            echo '<p class="card-text text_limit">'.Str::limit($post->content,260).'</p>
                  <p class="card-text text_limit">';
                
            echo '</p><a href="'.route('show_single', $post->url_clean).'" class="btn btn-primary">Leer mas</a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br></br>';

    ?>
@endforeach
</div>
{!! $posts->render() !!}
```

What would be the best way to configure the files so that they always load properly? I await your answers, thank you very much.

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for, I've already seen that answer, but thanks

Comment: One quick thing is to have all basic layout having all common CSS and JS declaration at master template. If you need specific styling or javascript for some blades, you could @yield('styles') or @yield('scripts') in the template, and have additional styling or scripts on each page, if needed. One little thing, make sure you import jquery before bootstrap as it needs it to work properly